# Selecting custom attributes within a <div> with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a table that has the following td:

```
<td>
      <div id="spcheck">
         <div id="check" 
              data-1='<%# Eval("sth1") %>' 
              data-2='<%# Eval("sth2") %>' 
              data-3='<%# Eval("sth3") %>'>
              <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server"/>
          </div>
      </div>
</td>
```

This  is the last one. It has custom attributes as you can see. I need to get the values data-1, data-2 and data-3 if have the checkbox cheked. I have the folowing code that gets each tr but I need to go inside the td and get the attribute values:

```
$('#ListView2_itemPlaceholderContainer tbody tr').each(function () {
                // I GET THE <TR>
                $(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
                    // I NEED THIS CODE
                    });
                });
            });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the attributes are on the div , you need to find the div first and get the attributes of the div..  You can use the `.attr()` on the div to get them

```
 $(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
         var $closestDiv = $(this).closest('div');  // Find the div

         var $data1 = $closestDiv.attr('data-1');  // data-1
         var $data2 = $closestDiv.attr('data-2');  // data-2
         var $data3 = $closestDiv.attr('data-3');  // data-3
  });
```

Comment: Thank you!! I've choosen this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#ListView2_itemPlaceholderContainer tbody tr').each(function () {
    $(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
           var dataElement = $(this).closest('[data-1]');

           var data1 = dataElement.data('1');
           var data2 = dataElement.data('2');
           var data3 = dataElement.data('3');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr('data-1');
```

should do the trick

see [jQuery manual entry](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for attr